# What can I do if I want to further discuss a specific answer to a question?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-overflow

If I have a question about the whole answers of a question, and it is related to that page, what can I do?
I think it's a bit of a "bug" of this site (lack of community based questions and answers).
Does anyone agree with me?

Comment: I've made quite a substantial edit there for various reasons. Could you check if specifically the title there still reflects what you wanted to ask?

Comment: I think the only word spelled correct in that whole thing was the F word (preemptive edit so this comment won't get flagged/deleted).

Comment: Once you reach 20 rep, you can take it to [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: @Won't You mean except for the quote, right?

Comment: Someone has done a pretty good job at creating an MSO question-posting bot.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I understood you correctly.

If you're asking about requesting details/clarification on all answers of the question, you can:

- Take it to chat, it requires 20 reputation points.
- Comment on the question itself, if it's not *your* question, it'll take 50 reputation points.

Comment: @Troyen: After a quick check, it turned out you're right! Corrected, thank you.